# Is it possible to Implement Job Repository of Spring Batch using any of the latest versions of MongoDB with transactional support?

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I have gone through several implementation of job repository using mongo dB but couldn't find any stable one, and that support transactions in job repository. I have also read a note, that mongo DB is not recommended for job repository as it does not support transactions. So need to know the possibilities of implement job repository using any latest versions of mongo DB with transactional support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also read a note, that mongo DB is not recommended for job repository as it does not support transactions.

MongoDB added support for transactions in [v4](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions). There is a feature request against Spring Batch to use MongoDB as a job repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/877, but this feature has not been implemented yet.

Comment: So, is it possible to implement a job repo with transaction using mongo DB? Will that be  available on any upcoming version of the spring batch?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Yes there is a plan to consider it, but we did not decide in which version  to include it yet. You can follow updates on the issues.